Problem With Raycast, it seem that the distance is infinite which made it so it constantly checked the wall as true no matter the distance
I tried Overlapping Circle, and differnt ways to Raycast but none worked. I expect for the Wall Sliding to be true only when the player is touching the wall. Currently when the player jumps when facing the wall at any distance, you can spam the walljump function, however this only happens when the player is in the air while moving.
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float horizontal;
    public float speed;
    public float jumpingPower;
    private bool isFacingRight = true;

    public bool wallSliding = false;
    public float slidingSpeed;
    
    public bool check;

    private bool isWallJumping;
    private float wallJumpingDirection;
    public float wallJumpingTime = 0.2f;
    private float wallJumpingCounter;
    private float wallJumpingDuration = 0.4f;

    private Vector2 wallJumpingPower = new Vector2(7f, 16f);



    [SerializeField] private Rigidbody2D rb;
    [SerializeField] private Transform groundCheck;
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask groundLayer;
    [SerializeField] private Transform wallCheck;
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask wallLayer;


    void Update()
    {
        horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && IsGrounded())
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpingPower);
        }

        if (Input.GetButtonUp("Jump") && rb.velocity.y > 0f)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, rb.velocity.y * 0.5f);
        }

        WallSlide();
        WallJump();
        if (!isWallJumping)
        {
            Flip();
        }
        IsWalled();
    }



    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (!isWallJumping)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(horizontal * speed, rb.velocity.y);
        }
    }




    private bool IsGrounded()
    {
        return Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, 0.2f, groundLayer);
    }



    private void IsWalled()
    {   float distance = 0.2f;
        Vector3 fwd = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);
        check = Physics2D.Raycast(wallCheck.position, fwd, distance,wallLayer);
    }

    private void WallSlide()
    {
        if (!IsGrounded() && (horizontal > 0.000001f || horizontal < 0.00000f))
        {   
            if (horizontal < 0f){
                rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, Mathf.Clamp(rb.velocity.y, -slidingSpeed, float.MaxValue));
            }
            
        }
        else{
         wallSliding = false;
        }
    }


    private void WallJump()
    {
        if (wallSliding)
        {
            isWallJumping = false;
            wallJumpingDirection = -transform.localScale.x;
            wallJumpingCounter = wallJumpingTime;

            CancelInvoke(nameof(StopWallJumping));
        }
        else
        {
            wallJumpingCounter -= Time.deltaTime;
        }

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && wallJumpingCounter > 0f)
        {
            isWallJumping = true;
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(wallJumpingDirection * wallJumpingPower.x, wallJumpingPower.y);
            wallJumpingCounter = 0f;

            if (transform.localScale.x != wallJumpingDirection)
            {
                isFacingRight = !isFacingRight;
                Vector3 localScale = transform.localScale;
                localScale.x *= -1f;
                transform.localScale = localScale;
            }

            Invoke(nameof(StopWallJumping), wallJumpingDuration);
        }
    }

    private void StopWallJumping()
    {
        isWallJumping = false;
    }


    private void Flip()
    {
        if (isFacingRight && horizontal < 0f || !isFacingRight && horizontal > 0f)
        {
            isFacingRight = !isFacingRight;
            Vector3 localScale = transform.localScale;
            localScale.x *= -1f;
            transform.localScale = localScale;
        }
    }
}

